# Proof relating to Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: divisibility, recursive-algorithms

The question is as follows:

(1): Let *m* and *n* be positive integers with *n* < *m* and let *r* be the remainder when *m* is divided by *n*. Prove that

$$r < \frac m2$$

(2): The Euclidean Algorithm for the positive integers $r_0 > r_1$works by repeated division with remainders.

$$r_0 = q_1r_1 + r_2, 0\le r_2\le r_1,$$

$$r_1 = q_2r_2 + r_3, 0\le r_3\le r_2,$$

and so on...

$r_n$ is the greatest common divisor of $r_0$ and $r_1$ when the following $r$ is 0.

Show that if $r_0\le2^k$ with $k\ge1$, then $n\le 2k-1$.

I have answered part 1, but I left it here as I assume it is required for part 2.
Thanks.

Comment: I'd think this is easier to prove with contradiction. Assume $r \geq m/2$ It should be rather easy to argue to a contradiction from that

Comment: I have answered that part ruler501, thanks for confirming what I did was correct though. Please read again, it's the second part I am struggling with!

Comment: Sorry I missed that part. I must be reading too quickly. I'll look at that part now.

Comment: You should be able to prove this by induction on $k$. The point of part (1) is that when you do two steps of the Euclidean algorithm, the larger number is less than half what the original larger number was.